How to pass output variable from child to grand parent
I spend 10 hours to try to understand why the output value of a ressource is empty without success.
The structure of me folder is :

tf

main.tf
outputs.tf
variables.tf
terraform.tfvars
modules/

share/

iam/

main.tf
outputs.tf
variables.tf




integration/

main.tf
variables.tf
outputs.tf
lambda/

main.tf
variables.tf
outputs.tf









I would like to pass output from tf/modules/share/iam/outputs.tf from tf/modules/integration/lambda/main.tf
In tf/modules/integration/lambda/main.tf
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role" {
  name        = "${var.project_name}_lambda_role"
  description = "${var.project_name} : lambda access"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "lambda.amazonaws.com",
          "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": "LambdaAssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

In tf/modules/integration/lambda/outputs.tf
output "iam_lambda_role_arn" {
  description = "ARN of the lambda execution role"
  value       = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn
}


In  tf/main.tf
module "share_iam" {
  source = "./modules/share/iam"
  # variable send to module
}

module "integration" {
  source                    = "./modules/integration"
  # variable send to module
  share_iam_lambda_role_arn = module.share_iam.iam_lambda_role_arn
  
}


in tf/modules/integration/variables.tf
variable "share_iam_lambda_role_arn" {
  type    = string
  default = ""
}

In tf/modules/integration/main.tf
module "lambda" {
  source                    = "./lambda"
  share_iam_lambda_role_arn = var.share_iam_lambda_role_arn
}

then in tf/modules/integration/lambda/variables.tf
variable "share_iam_lambda_role_arn" {
  type    = string
  default = ""
}

and in tf/modules/integration/lambda/main.tf
resource "aws_lambda_function" "entry_process_add" {
   ...
  role          = var.share_iam_lambda_role_arn
  ...
}

You know everything !!
Terraform validate + terraform plan  have no error code
But when I do an apply, I have this error :slight_smile:
Error: creating Lambda Function (entry_process_add): operation error Lambda: CreateFunction, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: e46d89ea-9265-4f09-b54c-80a1114bdbba, api error ValidationException: 1 validation error detected: Value '' at 'role' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: arn:(aws[a-zA-Z-]*)?:iam::\d{12}:role/?[a-zA-Z_0-9+=,.@\-_/]+
│ 
│   with module.integration.module.apigateway.module.lambda.aws_lambda_function.entry_process_add,
│   on modules/integration/lambda/main.tf line 5, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "entry_process_add":
│    5: resource "aws_lambda_function" "entry_process_add" {

The value of "var.share_iam_lambda_role_arn" is empy but the ressource "resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role"  has been well created in AWS
The code show how I process

I am a bit confused by your output. it says module.integration.module.apigateway.module.lambda.aws_lambda_function.entry_process_add so look like your calling the integration module which calls api gateway module that then calls lambda module. so you need to pass the variable thourgh that layer if thats how this is all actually connected. Can you maybe show how apigateway module is calling the lambda module?
